# How to dynamically formulate a statictext listing

Tags: python, wxpython, iteration

I'm trying to create a function that on call formulates a listing in a panel using the statictext widget. I'm pulling the info from a sql table which contains a name, phone, and email. Here is my example and hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do.

```
info = [('name1','phone1','email1'),('name2','phone2','email2'),
('name3','phone3','email3')]

for name,phone,email in info:
    x = 0
    y = 0
    wx.StaticText(self.Panel,-1,str(name),pos=(10+x,40+y))
    wx.StaticText(self.Panel,-1,str(phone),pos=(100+x,40+y))
    wx.StaticText(self.Panel,-1,str(email),pos=(190+x,40+y))
    x = x + 90
    y = y + 30
```

Now I would think this would work. Am I missing something, overlooking something?? What happens is alot of the info doesn't show up but you can see that somewhere it's clipping with words overlapping each other.

TRYING TO GET THIS EFFECT:

name1    phone1    email1

name2    phone2    email2

name3    phone3    email3

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
x = 0
y = 0
for name, phone, email in info:        
    wx.StaticText(self.Panel, -1, str(name),  pos=(10+x,40+y))
    wx.StaticText(self.Panel, -1, str(phone), pos=(100+x,40+y))
    wx.StaticText(self.Panel, -1, str(email), pos=(190+x,40+y))

    y = y + 30
```

Comment: better than what was happening but still no. With this I get a bit of a staircase effect and still overlapping. I should note there are about 10 tuples in my (info)list. I've edited my post to show what I'm trying to get

Comment: @Isov5 try find a pencil and paper, draw some rect, calculate coordinates, and come back to code; improve your math skills

Comment: Um, well no. I did this same procedure manually and it worked fine. It only acts different when I use iteration. And I can't manually insert these statictext because it's suppose to pull and display info dynamically.

Comment: @Isov5 hi, I remove x = x + 90, you make this change, and see whether staircase effect disapear

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a sizer

```
import wx

info = [('name1','phone1','email1'),('name2','phone2','email2'),
('name3','phone3','email3')]

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        panel= wx.Panel(self)
        sizer= wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        grid_sizer= wx.GridSizer(len(info),3,5,5)
        for person in info:
            for detail in person:
                text= wx.StaticText(panel,label=detail)
                grid_sizer.Add(text)
        sizer.Add(grid_sizer,0,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,10)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.Show()

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
       Frame(None)
       return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app= App(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```